# MKS Base V1.4 does not recognize my PCB MK3 heat bed

Tags: marlin, firmware, heated-bed, thermistor, bed

I am using an MKS base V1.4 board, PCB MK3 dual-power heat bed, and Marlin 2.0.1. My printer does not recognize my heat bed. I cannot control it and I cannot even see the temp. Actually, my printer LCD shows nothing where it has to show the bed temp.

My bed is working fine when it's connected directly to a 12 V power supply.
Pin Definings on firmware are checked and fine. The thermistor is checked and fine. Bed solderings are checked and fine.